# Implementing MATLAB like graphical editor in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, drag-and-drop, editor, graphic

I want to implement the Graphical Editor with drag and drop the controls and also it should have a docking features like in Eclipse in Eclipse JAVA.

Does anyone know of any 3rd party products that already do something like this?

If not then then a simple level, Are there any good samples on the net for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Eclipse Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/platform/) or [NetBeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/). Both are highly customizable, extendable, and already have the controls done for you - you'd only need to implement the MATLAB-related stuff.